# Chrome freezes when playing videos from Rackspace cloudfiles

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, freeze

Can't seem to get chrome to play videos with html5 video tag when I host them on a Rackspace cloudfiles server.

Works perfectly on the regular hosting, but as soon as I link the video with the rackspace cdn url, Chrome freezes (total freeze, website UI completely blocked - after a while Chrome pops a message saying "The following page has become unresponsive bla bla bla").

The video file is fine as it's same as when I link to the regular hosting.

Did a bit of spying on the requests, and I initially thought the problem was that the webm files were serverd by default as application/octet-stream mime-type. I lodged a ticket to rackspace and they gave me a way to force the mime-type when uploading the file. Did that, and the file is now correctly sent as video/webm.. but Chrome still freezes.

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

**EDIT**: using [iheartvideo](http://iheartvideo.appspot.com/), loading the video from rackspace triggers a MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED. Same video off local web server works totally fine (??)

**EDIT 2**: Happens on both mac and windows with latest mainstream chrome

**EDIT 3**: curl -I results:

*Rackspace (no worky):*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.7.65
Content-Type: video/webm
Last-Modified: Thu, 24 Feb 2011 23:45:12 GMT
ETag: 7029f83b241aa691859012dfa047e20d
Content-Length: 20173074
Cache-Control: public, max-age=900
Expires: Fri, 25 Feb 2011 01:32:11 GMT
Date: Fri, 25 Feb 2011 01:17:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

*Web Server (worky)*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 25 Feb 2011 01:17:51 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 24 Feb 2011 03:56:26 GMT
ETag: "11a0b47-133d112-49cff32940e80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 20173074
Content-Type: text/plain
```

**EDIT 4**: For those interested, this is what the rackscape crew told me to do to set a webm content type on a file:

> The file browser is not smart enough
>   to determine the content type
>   video/webm. Unfortunately, there is
>   not a way to change the content type
>   of a file that has already been
>   uploaded.
>
> You'll need to use one of the API to
>   re-upload your files with the correct
>   content type.
>
> You can also use curl from a
>   linux/MacOS command line if available.
>
> Using your username and api key run
>   this command...

```
curl -I -X GET -H "X-Auth-User: USERNAME" -H "X-Auth-Key: API_KEY" https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0
```

> From the output there are 2 important
>   values.

```
X-Storage-Url: https://storage101.......
X-Storage-Token: Long hash
```

> You can upload the files with,

```
curl -X PUT -T test.webm -H "Content-Type: video/webm" -H "Content-Length: FILESIZEINBYTE" -H "X-Auth-Token: TOKEN FROM RESPONSE ABOVE" https://STORAGE URL FROM RESPONSE ABOVE/test.webm
```

> You must specify the content type, and
>   you must give the correct length of
>   bytes of what is being uploaded.  If
>   not you will get an invalid request
>   error.

Comment: Not an answer at all, but just wanted to say/let you know that I have had the exact same issue with pretty much the same replies from Rackspace. In the end, I had the luxury of switching to Amazon where I can change the MIME types of the files with Cyberduck on the fly and (for some reason) Chrome does not crash. Not sure if this is an option for you though.

Comment: @Samuel. What sort of update could you want? I haven't experienced the problem in a while so I'm guessing it's been fixed by Rackspace. Otherwise, I'd suggest the fix in Edit 4

Comment: Ok, it worked for me after uploading the videos using CyberDuck (but not with the rackspace webapp)

Answer (score 1):

I work quite a bit with the Rackspace API.
Their API actually allows you to set a container as streaming enabled. My first instinct tells me that you haven't done this.
I stream various file types and they all work an absolute treat.

There is more information about CDN Streaming Enabled containers here: 
    http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Streaming-CDN-Enabled_Containers-d1f3721.html

Hopefully this helps, but if not let me know and I don't mind putting some PHP example code together to help you along.
Its all quite easy, but getting your head around the various API operations that Rackspace have implemented can sometimes be a daunting task.

Comment: Thanks for the late contribution (this is quite an old question actually). I don't remember seeing this at the time. Do you know if there's a way to make a container Streaming Enabled from the management console? (this is not a an API question)

Comment: Actually, their new Cloud Control Panel (mycloud.rackspace.com) shows the streaming url when you click on the cog wheel next to the container. Their old one (manage.rackspacecloud.com) doesn't.

Comment: That's weird. I'll take a look in a moment on the new console but that could be an error on their part. To enable the steaming container you had to tell it to stream via am API call. I would be melted to hit the container with a streaming command and see what happens. I know this is an old question, but it appeared in my list as unanswered and I do hate leaving questions unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a concrete answer, just some thoughts:

1. what about in other browsers?
2. it works on the web server with the content type above is text/plain so why force to video/webm?
3. can Rackspace provide you (or can you find on their site or someone else's) some sample content that does play so you can inspect it?

You could try the free trial from Brightcove or Bitgravity and see if that works...